# Installing XHProf on Ubuntu Server

Tags: php, ubuntu, xhprof

I have tried the following tutorials, as well as others:

http://akyl.net/how-install-xhprof-profiler-ubuntu

http://erichogue.ca/2011/03/linux/profiling-a-php-application/

I am continually getting the following error message(s):

```
running: make
/bin/bash /tmp/pear/install/pear-build-fieldnation1Iqjyy/xhprof-0.9.2/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/tmp/pear/install/xhprof/extension -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-fieldnation1Iqjyy/xhprof-0.9.2/include -I/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-fieldnation1Iqjyy/xhprof-0.9.2/main -I/tmp/pear/install/xhprof/extension -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /tmp/pear/install/xhprof/extension/xhprof.c -o xhprof.lo
libtool: compile:  cc -I. -I/tmp/pear/install/xhprof/extension -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-fieldnation1Iqjyy/xhprof-0.9.2/include -I/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-fieldnation1Iqjyy/xhprof-0.9.2/main -I/tmp/pear/install/xhprof/extension -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /tmp/pear/install/xhprof/extension/xhprof.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/xhprof.o
In file included from /usr/include/php5/main/php.h:33:0,
                 from /tmp/pear/install/xhprof/extension/xhprof.c:27:
/usr/include/php5/main/php_config.h:2396:0: warning: "_GNU_SOURCE" redefined [enabled by default]
/tmp/pear/install/xhprof/extension/xhprof.c:24:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
/tmp/pear/install/xhprof/extension/xhprof.c:236:1: warning: 'visibility' attribute ignored [-Wattributes]
/tmp/pear/install/xhprof/extension/xhprof.c:240:28: warning: 'visibility' attribute ignored [-Wattributes]
/tmp/pear/install/xhprof/extension/xhprof.c: In function 'hp_get_function_name':
/tmp/pear/install/xhprof/extension/xhprof.c:898:10: warning: assignment discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]
/tmp/pear/install/xhprof/extension/xhprof.c:909:13: warning: assignment discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]
/tmp/pear/install/xhprof/extension/xhprof.c:911:13: warning: assignment discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]
/tmp/pear/install/xhprof/extension/xhprof.c:930:34: error: 'znode_op' has no member named 'u'
/tmp/pear/install/xhprof/extension/xhprof.c:963:9: warning: passing argument 1 of 'hp_get_base_filename' discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]
/tmp/pear/install/xhprof/extension/xhprof.c:856:14: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
/tmp/pear/install/xhprof/extension/xhprof.c: In function 'hp_execute_internal':
/tmp/pear/install/xhprof/extension/xhprof.c:1650:24: error: 'znode_op' has no member named 'u'
/tmp/pear/install/xhprof/extension/xhprof.c:1651:59: error: 'struct <anonymous>' has no member named 'return_reference'
/tmp/pear/install/xhprof/extension/xhprof.c:1652:25: error: 'znode_op' has no member named 'u'
/tmp/pear/install/xhprof/extension/xhprof.c: In function 'hp_compile_file':
/tmp/pear/install/xhprof/extension/xhprof.c:1683:3: warning: passing argument 1 of 'hp_get_base_filename' discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]
/tmp/pear/install/xhprof/extension/xhprof.c:856:14: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
make: *** [xhprof.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

Basically, 'make' is not able to run. How do I get past this?

Comment: Are you installing it via `pecl`?

Comment: I've ran    pecl install xhprof    and ended up with the error above

Comment: I'm having this same error.  Did you ever figure out how to get past it?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I don't remember anymore why I wanted this, but I don't recall getting past it. Its been so long I imagine it would be out-of-date at this point anyways. The PECL listing shows it hasn't been updated in almost 4 years, and I'm doing all new development in PHP7+ so I don't even know if this is a tool I'd use for profiling at this time. Sorry! If you figure this out please post back here and I'll accept it as a solution!

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue, got it fixed using these steps:

Download "xhprof" package:

- cd /extension/
- phpize
- ./configure --with-php-config=
- make
- make install
- make test

Now add below lines in php.ini:

- [xhprof]
- extension=xhprof.so
- xhprof.output_dir="directory_for_storing_xhprof_runs"

Now: **apache restart**

Answer (score 0):

Successfully completed the make process using the latest update from http://pecl.php.net/package/xhprof